# Adding to Ribbon at run time works once

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

Hi I'm trying to add the current open contacts phone numbers to a ribbon.

I have created the ribbon and added a SplitButton which will contain the phone numbers.

In 'ThisAddin' when the current explorer changes it triggers an event which simply gets the item type. If its a contact it calls

```
//ThisAddin.cs on explorer change event - if is contact run:    

Globals.Ribbons.CallContact.AddButton(contactItem.BusinessTelephoneNumber);  



//Ribbon class
internal void AddButton(string name)
    {            
        if (name != null && name.Count() > 2)
        {
            RibbonButton item = Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonButton();
            item.Label = name;
            item.ShowLabel = true;
            this.newSplit.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

This works once, first time opening a contact the phone number is displayed in the ribbon. Opening another contact window will cause the ribbon items to be added but are blank and null.

I'm simply trying to add the contacts phone numbers to the ribbon and leave them there while the user can open another contact and the same code runs adding the phone numbers to the ribbon.

I don't need to keep reference to the items once they are added. Thank you for the help. I feel there needs to be an invoke in here somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must tell Outlook to refresh the ribbon. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-updating-the-controls-on-a-ribbon-at-run-time?view=vs-2019 for the sample code.

You will need to specify a callback to retrieve the button's caption instead of hard-coding it in the ribbon's XML.

Note that since you can have multiple inspectors open, you must provide data specific to each item opened in its own inspector.

Answer (score 0):

The Ribbon UI is a static thing because it is loaded once at startup (or before the window is shown). The best what you can do is to define callbacks and get them called wherever you need. For example, you can define 'getVisible' callback for your ribbon controls instead of adding new elements at runtime.

The [IRibbonUI.Invalidate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribbonui.invalidate) method invalidates the cached values for all of the controls of the Ribbon user interface.

You can customize the Ribbon UI by using callback procedures in COM add-ins. For each of the callbacks that the add-in implements, the responses are cached.

For example, if an add-in writer implements the getImage callback procedure for a button, the function is called once, the image loads, and then if the image needs to be updated, the cached image is used instead of recalling the procedure. This process remains in place until the add-in signals that the cached values are invalid by using the Invalidate method, at which time, the callback procedure is again called and the return response is cached. The add-in can then force an immediate update of the UI by calling the Refresh method.

```
<customUI … OnLoad="MyAddinInitialize" …>


Dim MyRibbon As IRibbonUI 

Sub MyAddInInitialize(Ribbon As IRibbonUI) 
 Set MyRibbon = Ribbon 
End Sub 

Sub myFunction() 
 MyRibbon.Invalidate() ' Invalidates the caches of all of this add-in's controls 
End Sub
```

The Fluent UI is described in-depth in the following articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12))

Also, you may find the [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2019) helpful. Note, you can export an existing custom ribbon UI to the XML and continue dealing with a raw markup.